# c# get now playing info for video or audio program

Tags: c#, winamp

I would like to know how to get the currently playing song/video from commons players. I know this is possible as a dll for mirc has done this for years (but its support is dead and doesn't work any more).

I've tried searching for ways to do this and even asking in forums (Winamp specifically). I'm most interested in getting info from Winamp and MPC-HC. Thanks.